# 'No Cells' After applying autofilter: Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am autofiltering a range of cells in which case there might be an instance where there are no cells that meet the criteria of the filter (there are no cells with 'Yes' in the column I am looking at). When this happens, my program returns the error 'No Cells.' How can I set up error handling so that my program proceeds despite this? I have tried `On Error Resume Next` after the autofilter line, but it will not reach that line because it is stuck on the filter line.

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(counter, LstCol1)).AutoFilter Field:=z, Criteria1:="Yes"
    Set rngFilter_Yes = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), _
    .Columns(2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error Resume Next <- doesn't reach this line :(
```

Comment: I'd imagine you may see a few answers / comments letting you know this is probably not the best way to handle things as this will continue regardless of the type of error rather than the specific issue you're encountering. [The New Documentation Section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5411/error-handling#t=2016072214573443664) has content on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `On Error Resume Next` needs to preceed your statement like this:

```
On Error Resume Next ' ignores all errors and proceeds
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(counter, LstCol1)).AutoFilter Field:=z, Criteria1:="Yes"
Set rngFilter_Yes = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), _
.Columns(2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error Goto 0 'Returns the program to normal error handling state
```